# Share a global variable in flask among multiple gevent workers

Tags: python, flask, multiprocessing, gunicorn, gevent

In my Flask application I keep a global variable to store the current states of running tasks, but it cannot be shared by different gevent workers.

`g` is used to store global data in Flask application, however `g` will be reset after each request.

How can I achieve this without use of redis or any other storage between processes?

Comment: any solution? I have a very similar scenario

Comment: @FrancescoPegoraro avoid using global states in flask apps, use a intermediate storage such as mq or redis.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up using, it's not worth it.